# Count number of unique value for multiples column Mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have a table like this and I would like to get the number of distinct value for these 3 column (**string_2** **string_2** and **string_3**)

I know how to do a distinct and count in mysql, but in this case, I dont know how to count different distinct value for multiple column

[image]

The input I would like to have is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `count` and `distinct`:

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct string_1) AS string_1, 
    count(distinct string_2) AS string_2, 
    count(distinct string_3) AS string_3 
FROM table_name
```